# Changing the enumerate numbering style

Tags: enumerate

Is it possible to change the enumerate style from:

1.

2.

3.

to

(1)

(2)

(3)

?

I only know how to change it to roman letters.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Right now I try the following

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\section{Bla bla bla}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which package do you use? Please provide a complete minimal working example showing your current issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all such changes, unless you are addicted to tinkering, I find the [enumitem](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/enumitem.html) package generally easy and reliable. In your case, you might have (for instance)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\arabic*)}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

If you use further levels of enumeration, you might need to alter those too.